# Align Logo with bottom of Navbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to re-design / update the theme of my site to match the our organizational brand guide. I am also trying to write some of the elements to make life easier in the long run from how we currently do things. I am trying to create dual navs with a logo in the middle using w3school css. I can't seem to make everything bottom aligned. Please check my code and let me know what to change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<style>
    .hdr {
        background-color: #022a3a;
    }

    ul.breadcrumb {
        padding: 5px 8px;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    ul.breadcrumb li {
        display: inline;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    ul.breadcrumb li+li::before {
        padding: 4px;
        color: #fffef9;
        content: "/\00a0";
    }

    ul.breadcrumb li a {
        color: #fffef9;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul.breadcrumb li a:hover {
        color: #e8b00f;
        font-weight: 900;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    ul.social {
        padding: 5px 8px;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    ul.social li {
        color: #fffef9;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    ul.social li+li::before {
        padding: 4px;
        color: #fffef9;
        /* content: "/\00a0"; */
    }

    ul.social li a {
        color: #fffef9;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul.social li a:hover {
        color: #e8b00f;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #logo {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    }

    .sitelogo {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 78px;
        width: 260px;
        outline: none;
        background: transparent url("http://www.navy.mil/imgs/americas-navy-globe.png") no-repeat 0 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        /* text-indent: -9000px; */
        text-indent: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #___gcse_0 {
        float: right;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .gsc-control-cse {
        width: 50%;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        border-color: #022a3a!important;
        background-color: #022a3a!important;
    }

    .gsc-search-button-v2,
    .gsc-search-button-v2:focus {
        border-color: #C6CCD0!important;
        background-color: #0076a9!important;
        background-image: none;
        filter: none;
    }

    .gsc-search-button-v2:hover {
        border-color: #C6CCD0!important;
        background-color: #e8b00f!important;
        background-image: none;
        filter: none;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <div class="hdr">
        <div class="w3-content" style="max-width: 1200px;">
            <div class="w3-row">
                <div class="w3-col s9">

                    <!-- Start Sit Collection Breadcrumbs -->
                    <ul class="breadcrumb">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pictures</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Summer 15</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Italy</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- End Sit Collection Breadcrumbs -->
                </div>
                <div class="w3-col s3">

                    <!-- Start Social Media Links -->
                    <ul class="social">
                        <li>Follow Us On:</li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Follow Us On Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Follow Us On Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Follow Us On Flickr"><i class="fab fa-flickr"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Follow Us On Wordpress"><i class="fab fa-wordpress"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Follow Us On Youtube"><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- End Social Media Links -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-row">

                <!-- Start Site Logo -->
                <h1 id="logo">
                    <a class="sitelogo" href="#" title="Commander, Naval Surface Force, U.S. Pacific Home Page">
                        <span>Commander, Naval Surface Force, U.S. Pacific Home Page</span>
                    </a>
                </h1>
                <!-- Start Site Logo -->

                <!-- Start Site Search Box -->
                <div>
                    <script>
                        (function() {
                            var cx = '005604968521978876037:p1vcbb__lzm';
                            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                            gcse.async = true;
                            gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                                '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
                        })();
                    </script>
                    <div id="___gcse_0">
                        <div class="gsc-control-cse gsc-control-cse-en">
                            <div class="gsc-control-wrapper-cse" dir="ltr">
                                <form class="gsc-search-box gsc-search-box-tools" accept-charset="utf-8">
                                    <table class="gsc-search-box" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="gsc-input">
                                                    <div class="gsc-input-box " id="gsc-iw-id1">
                                                        <table style="width: 100%; padding: 0px;" id="gs_id50" class="gstl_50 " cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td id="gs_tti50" class="gsib_a"><input autocomplete="off" size="10" class="gsc-input" name="search" title="search" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; border: medium none; margin: 0px; height: auto; outline: medium none; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) url(&quot;https://www.google.com/cse/static/images/1x/googlelogo_lightgrey_46x16dp.png&quot;) no-repeat scroll left center; text-indent: 48px;"
                                                                            id="gsc-i-id1" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Custom Search" type="text"></td>
                                                                    <td class="gsib_b">
                                                                        <div class="gsst_b" id="gs_st50" dir="ltr"><a class="gsst_a" href="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;"><span class="gscb_a" id="gs_cb50">×</span></a></div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="gsc-search-button"><button class="gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2"><svg width="13" height="13" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><title>search</title><path d="m4.8495 7.8226c0.82666 0 1.5262-0.29146 2.0985-0.87438 0.57232-0.58292 0.86378-1.2877 0.87438-2.1144 0.010599-0.82666-0.28086-1.5262-0.87438-2.0985-0.59352-0.57232-1.293-0.86378-2.0985-0.87438-0.8055-0.010599-1.5103 0.28086-2.1144 0.87438-0.60414 0.59352-0.8956 1.293-0.87438 2.0985 0.021197 0.8055 0.31266 1.5103 0.87438 2.1144 0.56172 0.60414 1.2665 0.8956 2.1144 0.87438zm4.4695 0.2115 3.681 3.6819-1.259 1.284-3.6817-3.7 0.0019784-0.69479-0.090043-0.098846c-0.87973 0.76087-1.92 1.1413-3.1207 1.1413-1.3553 0-2.5025-0.46363-3.4417-1.3909s-1.4088-2.0686-1.4088-3.4239c0-1.3553 0.4696-2.4966 1.4088-3.4239 0.9392-0.92727 2.0864-1.3969 3.4417-1.4088 1.3553-0.011889 2.4906 0.45771 3.406 1.4088 0.9154 0.95107 1.379 2.0924 1.3909 3.4239 0 1.2126-0.38043 2.2588-1.1413 3.1385l0.098834 0.090049z"></path></svg></button></td>
                                                <td class="gsc-clear-button">
                                                    <div class="gsc-clear-button" title="clear results">&nbsp;</div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </form>
                                <div class="gsc-results-wrapper-overlay">
                                    <div class="gsc-results-close-btn" tabindex="0"></div>
                                    <div class="gsc-tabsAreaInvisible">
                                        <div class="gsc-tabHeader gsc-inline-block gsc-tabhActive">Custom Search</div><span class="gs-spacer"> </span></div>
                                    <div class="gsc-tabsAreaInvisible"></div>
                                    <div class="gsc-above-wrapper-area-invisible">
                                        <table class="gsc-above-wrapper-area-container" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="gsc-result-info-container">
                                                        <div class="gsc-result-info-invisible"></div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="gsc-orderby-container">
                                                        <div class="gsc-orderby-invisible">
                                                            <div class="gsc-orderby-label gsc-inline-block">Sort by:</div>
                                                            <div class="gsc-option-menu-container gsc-inline-block">
                                                                <div class="gsc-selected-option-container gsc-inline-block">
                                                                    <div class="gsc-selected-option">Relevance</div>
                                                                    <div class="gsc-option-selector"></div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="gsc-option-menu-invisible">
                                                                    <div class="gsc-option-menu-item gsc-option-menu-item-highlighted">
                                                                        <div class="gsc-option">Relevance</div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="gsc-option-menu-item">
                                                                        <div class="gsc-option">Date</div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="gsc-adBlockInvisible"></div>
                                    <div class="gsc-wrapper">
                                        <div class="gsc-adBlockInvisible"></div>
                                        <div class="gsc-resultsbox-invisible">
                                            <div class="gsc-resultsRoot gsc-tabData gsc-tabdActive">
                                                <table class="gsc-resultsHeader" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="gsc-twiddleRegionCell">
                                                                <div class="gsc-twiddle">
                                                                    <div class="gsc-title">Web</div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="gsc-stats"></div>
                                                                <div class="gsc-results-selector gsc-all-results-active">
                                                                    <div class="gsc-result-selector gsc-one-result" title="show one result">&nbsp;</div>
                                                                    <div class="gsc-result-selector gsc-more-results" title="show more results">&nbsp;</div>
                                                                    <div class="gsc-result-selector gsc-all-results" title="show all results">&nbsp;</div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="gsc-configLabelCell"></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                <div>
                                                    <div class="gsc-expansionArea"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="gsc-modal-background-image" tabindex="0"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Site Search Box -->
            </div>
            <div class="w3-row w3-gray" style="height: 38.5px;">
                <div class="w3-col s5">

                    <!-- Start Global Navigation -->
                    <div class="w3-bar">
                        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">Home</a>
                        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Global Navigation -->
                </div>
                <div class="w3-col s2">
                    <img src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/crests/ashland_med.gif" width="50%" style="vertical-align: bottom!important;" />
                </div>
                <div class="w3-col s5">

                    <!-- Start Local Navigation -->
                    <div class="w3-bar">
                        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">Home</a>
                        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Local Navigation -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

[jsFiddle Attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/KhmerBoi1/813d459s/5/)

Comment: You want all the nav element to be aligned bottom?? or the whole section to the bottom?

Comment: No text should be moved. Just have image aligned with the bottom of the gray bar.

Comment: You're asking to overflow the content of another container(the header at the top in this case), so I don't think there is a 100% clean solution for that. If you know the dimensions of the image, you can do something like: <img src="https://www.public.navy.mil/surfor/crests/ashland_med.gif" width="50%" style="vertical-align: bottom!important;position: relative;bottom: 52px;"> . At this point, you can remove the vertical-align property and move the additional CSS I provided to a more appropriate location(not inline).

Comment: I will eventually be writing a query to dynamically chance the image src which may or may not be the same size. is there a way to accomplish this without applying position settings?